# Easy way to check for valid command line parameters?

Tags: perl

I'm looking for an easy way to check for a correct number of command line parameters, displaying a usage message if an error occurs and then immediately exit.

I thought of something like

```
if (@ARGV < 3) {
  print STDERR "Usage: $0 PATTERN [FILE...]\n";
  exit 1;
}
```

Is this a valid pattern?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Also, I would STRONGLY suggest using the idiomatic way of processing command line arguments in Perl, `Getopt::Long` module (and start using named parameters and not position-based ones).

You don't really CARE if you have <3 parameters. You usually care if you have parameters a, b and C present.

As far as command line interface design, 3 parameters is about where the cut-off is between positional parameters (`cmd <arg1> <arg2>`) vs. named parameters in any order (`cmd -arg1 <arg1> -arg2 <arg2>`).

So you are better off doing:

```
use Getopt::Long;
my %args;
GetOptions(\%args,
           "arg1=s",
           "arg2=s",
           "arg3=s",
) or die "Invalid arguments!";
die "Missing -arg1!" unless $args{arg1};
die "Missing -arg2!" unless $args{arg2};
die "Missing -arg3!" unless $args{arg3};
```

Answer (score 15):

Another common way to do that is to use [die](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html)

```
die "Usage: $0 PATTERN [FILE...]\n" if @ARGV < 3;
```

You can get more help on the `@ARGV` special variable at your command line:

```
perldoc -v @ARGV
```

Answer (score 6):

Yes, it is fine. `@ARGV` contains the command-line arguments and evaluates in scalar context to their number.

(Though it looks like you meant `@ARGV < 2` or `< 1` from your error message.)

Answer (score 1):

Use $#ARGV to get total number of passed argument to a perl script like so:

```
if (@#ARGV < 4)
```

I've used before and worked as shown in http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-pass-perl-command-line-arguments/.

See the original documentation at http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html, it states that:

> @ARGV
>
> The array @ARGV contains the command-line arguments intended for the script. $#ARGV is  generally the number of arguments minus one, because $ARGV[0] is the first argument, not the program's command name itself. See $0 for the command name.

Comment: That's not right. `scalar @ARGV` is one less than the length of the real argv *because* Perl has gone to the trouble of removing the program name from the array that it presents to you. `$#ARGV` is accounting for the program name twice.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it depends on your level of distrust (you did not specify what parameters are actually expected):

- `@ARGV < 3` just checks whether there are less than three parameters
- What about extra parameters?
- What about the type (or syntax) of each parameter?
- What about the semantics of each parameter (e.g. a file that must exist)?

As suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/5022789/6607497 using `Getopt::Long` is a first step, but even `arg1=s` will allow the string to be anything, even empty.

As said above, you can extend `Getopt::Long` with your own checking functions (that would exceed the typical size of an answer, specifically when considering the very short (and little detailed) question), but a pattern could look like this:

```perl
# parse options
sub get_options()
{
    my $result = 1;
    my %options = ('angular-offset=f' => \$angular_offset,
                   'destination-point=s' => check_pair_param(\@p_dest),
                   'iteration-count=i' => check_positive_param(\$count),
                   'speed=f' => check_speed_param(\$speed),
                   'starting-point=s' => check_pair_param(\@p_start),
                   'translation-vector=s' => check_pair_param(\@v_transl),
                   'verbosity=i' => \$verbosity);

    use Getopt::Long;

    if (!GetOptions(%options))
    {
        print STDERR "valid options for $0 are:\n";
        foreach my $opt (sort(keys %options)) {
#...
        }
        print STDERR "\n";
        undef $result;
    }
    return $result;
}
```

In the example `check_positive_param` will check whether the parameter is a positive number (`GetOptions` and `=i` ensures that it's an integer already), maybe like this (warning: **closures ahead**):

```perl
# check for positive number
sub check_positive_param($)
{
    my $tgt_ref = shift;

    sub (;$$) {
        my ($name, $value) = @_;

        unless (defined($value)) {      # printable representation
            return $tgt_ref;
        } elsif ($value && $value > 0) {
            $$tgt_ref = $value;
        } else {
            $name = '--' . $name;
            die "$value: not a positive value for $name!\n";
        }
    }
}
```

The closure also allows to print the value of the associated option variable, and the reason for using a closure is that you can check different option values that all need to be positive.

For example specifying `--it=-4` would result in an error message like this:

```text
-4: not a positive value for --iteration-count!
valid options for ../homing.pl are:
...
```

Similar checks could be written to check for existing files, readable files, valid host names, etc.

For repeating options where values are collected in arrays, it's a bit more tricky, but it works as well.

I'm not saying it's the most elegant way to do it, but it works rather well (also showing the list of valid options and their default value (in the part that is omitted), but that also wasn't part of the question).

Answer (score -3):

You can compare with $#ARGV instead the array @ARGV

```
if ($#ARGV < 3) { ...
```

Comment: Nope. `$ARGV` is the current filename used by `<>` and has no direct relation to `@ARGV`.  Any array, including `@ARGV`, can be used in a scalar context, where it means the number of elements.

Comment: @Juan: No, it doesn't work. Maybe you're thinking of `$#ARGV`?

Comment: ah yes, $#ARGV forgot the #, jaja

Comment: Note that `if ($#ARGV < 3)` means *if `@ARGV` has fewer than **four** elements*.